# Printer Friendly Layouts

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create a product ordering and invoicing system using PHP/MySQL. I am currently doing this in Microsoft Excel, purely because I can easily print out what's on screen and I know exactly what the output will be before printing.

Can the same result be acheived with a web-based system? For example once an order is complete, I want to be able to print out the invoice with everything within the width of an A4 page.

Is it simply a case of just specifying width properties on the tables? Also will I first need to load up a printer friendly version of the page or can I just click on a "Print" button which automatically prints out the printer friendly version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in CSS you can specify the "PRINT" version of a given class, so that when the user goes to print the page from the browser it formats differently than how it is displayed in the page.

Take a look at this: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can:

```
1. click on printer and use another template for printable version
2. use <link media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css">
this CSS will be used for print version only
3. to print use $(window).print() ;)
```

Comment: step 3 is jQuery advice, no? I don't think the OP asked anything about jQuery

Comment: $(window).print() the same as window.print()